# Facebook Graph API only get own posts without shared posts

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm new to the Facebook API with PHP, and so far, I've succeeded in retrieving all the posts for my feed. But, I want to retrieve only the posts I have published, so nothing I have shared (that's what's included when I use the `/posts`) nor do I want messages placed on my feed by someone else (that's what I get using `/feed`)

Below an example of my call:

```
$data  = file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/$page_name/posts?limit=$limit&access_token=$access_token");
```

Any thoughts on this? Should I be using the facebook PHP SDK, or can it be done with a `file_get_contents`?

I have tried the `"&with="` location filter, but I have no idea what that should do. Also I have tried adding `"?filter="` `app_$app_id`, but that had no effect either.

Comment: There is no way to filter this in your API call. You’ll have to take what /posts gets you, and then filter out the stuff you are not interested in on your end. Either check whether the `link` field is empty, or look at the `type` field. (So whether you use the PHP SDK, or make the HTTP request on your own, doesn’t really matter much here.)

Comment: Thanks. I'll rewrite the code then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per CBroe's comment, this is not possible and needs additional code.